# Trap ERR only works once?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that waits until a bunch of directories exist before starting a service. It basically consists of an infinite loop that breaks at the end, or continues if any of the needed directories aren't found. Simplified, the algorithm itself looks like

```
loop_while_false() {
    trap continue ERR
    while true; do
        printf .
        sleep 1
        false
        break
    done
    trap ERR
    echo
}
```

(I'm aware I could accomplish this particular behavior with `until` or `while !`, but that's tangential to the question.)

The first time I run this, I get the expected output of a long series of dots until I hit ^c. But if I run it again, I just get one dot. If I *don't* hit ^c, but redefine the loop to be finite, then, in a *new* shell, the trap works multiple times. But why is ^c breaking the trap for the life of the shell? Even weirder (I spent extra time on this while StackExchange was upgrading hardware) if you write the function this way, it doesn't break:

```
loop_while_noread() {
    trap continue ERR
    while true; do
        printf .
        read -t1 -n1
        break
    done
    trap ERR
    echo
}
```

Unless you run `loop_while_false` first, and kill it with ^c. Here's an example session:

```
$ trap -p
trap -- 'shell_session_update' EXIT
$ loop_while_noread 
...q
$ loop_while_noread 
...r
$ loop_while_noread 
....^C
$ loop_while_noread 
..q
$ trap -p
trap -- 'shell_session_update' EXIT
trap -- 'continue' ERR
$ loop_while_false 
.....^C
$ trap -p
trap -- 'shell_session_update' EXIT
trap -- 'continue' ERR
$ loop_while_false 
.
$ loop_while_noread 
.
```

It as if there's a weird relationship between `sleep` or `false` and `trap`. Is this expected behavior?

I'm using bash 3.2.57(1)-release on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: I can reproduce on Debian squeeze (bash `4.1.5(1)`), but not on Ubuntu 14.04 (bash `4.3.11(1)`). Looks like a bug was fixed.

Comment: Also happens in Ubuntu 12.04 (bash `4.2.25(1)`). Now, who's going to hunt through the changelog between 4.2.25 and 4.3.11?

Comment: Tempted to send a "philosophical" bug to [bashbug](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reporting-Bugs.html) about the bug reporting process itself, in that there is no obvious bug database to search through.

Comment: I can reproduce it on 4.3.11 and also 4.3.30. It's certainly a bug.

Comment: @rici something in my shell configuration might be interfering as well. I started it with the default Ubuntu 14.04 `.bashrc` and I can reproduce. Who knows what cruft I have accumulated and what in it helps.

Comment: @muru: that's interesting. I have no idea what setting that might be. Are you possibly redefining `sleep`?

Comment: @rici yes! I had `sleep () { command sleep "$1" && "${@:2}"; }` since I rarely used `sleep` by itself. That settles that.

Comment: @muru: ah right. That's more or less the same as my workaround, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly a bug. You can work around it by changing the sleep command to:

```
sleep 1||:
```

I can't find any bug reports, but I did a little poking against 4.3.30(1) with `gdb`, and established that after the `sleep 1` returns with an error (because it was interrupted), something fails in the execution of the `trap ERR` command, with the result that the `SIG_INPROGRESS` flag is never reset for `ERR`. That flag suppresses future execution of `trap ERR`, even though it is still enabled.

I didn't get into the part where "something fails in the execution"; when gdb steps over `parse_and_execute (trap_command, tag, flags);`, the function never returns and I end up back at the bash prompt, so I suppose that a longjmp happens at some point. (The `SIG_INPROGRESS` flag would be reset after `parse_and_execute` returns, so the fact that the function doesn't return explains why the flag is not reset.)

All this action is in `trap.c` inside `_run_trap_internal`.

Comment: I reported it using bashbug, such as it is.

Comment: @kojiro: I'll assume that someone who understands bash internals better than I do will deal with it, then. I added the workaround I discovered.

Comment: yes, one of those three people will surely do that. ;)

Comment: @kojiro: I didn't see your message on http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-02/index.html Is your outgoing mail working?

Comment: Probably not. I rarely bother setting up the low level *nix mail on OS X.